# How to run two-way ANOVA when continuously getting ValueError: must have at least one row in constraint matrix

Tags: matrix, error-handling, constraints, row, anova

When I try to run the ANOVA, I get a "ValueError: must have at least one row in constraint matrix" message. See an example table below and the code that I am trying to run. You can ignore the "recount" column for now!

| pecount | recount | rule | stage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

The code that I currently have is:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

data = pd.read_csv('errShift.csv')

# Check the first few rows of your data to verify the column name change
print(data.head())

# Create a model for the two-factor ANOVA
model = ols('pecount ~ C(rule) * C(stage)', data=data).fit()

# Perform the two-factor ANOVA
anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)

# Print the ANOVA table
print(anova_table)
```

I expect it to yield ANOVA results with pecount as dependent variable and stage and rule as independent variables.

Answer (score 0):

Update - I got it to work using the following code (the only difference I note is in line 10 by saying `data=data` vs. saying `data=df` aka what I named my `dataframe`, could this be what is yielding the error?):

```
# Importing libraries
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('errShift.csv')

# Performing two-way ANOVA
model = ols('pecount ~ C(rule) + C(stage)', data=df).fit()
anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, type=2)

# Print the result
print(anova_table)
```

It is working (by not yielding an error) but is yielding an odd ANOVA table with many NaN's. This is because I need to merge the dataframes together so that the columns have multiple different numbers in them (not just all 0s or all 1s) - as I have changed it to be.